# Extract all values between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

First off, my input is not well formed XML. So basically I have a bunch of tags. How can i use javascript/Regex to extract all values between the `<message>` tag?

Input:

```
<bad xml doc>
<a>dsda</a>
<message>hi</message>
<b></b>
<c>dsds</c>
<message>get this message too</message>
```

Output:

> hi
>       get this message too

Comment: Where does the XML come from?

Comment: A *malformated* document can NEVER be parsed correctly. Don't try to fix the symptoms. Fix the cause!

Comment: It's Error messages that have concatenated into one long string so it contains a lot of xml messages along with text. I just try to treat it as a text input and use js/regex to get all the values between <message> tags

Comment: Try this `/<message\s*>(.*?)<\/message\s*>/`.

Comment: Thank you Rdeys and dreyescat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the global flag:

```
var messages = text.match(/<message>(.*?)<\/message>/g).map(function (m) {
  return m.slice(9, -10);
})
console.log(messages.join('\r\n'));
```

```js
var text = '<bad xml doc>\
<a>dsda</a>\
<message>hi</message>\
<b></b>\
<c>dsds</c>\
<message>get this message too</message>';

var messages = text.match(/<message>(.*?)<\/message>/g).map(function (m) {
  return m.slice(9, -10);
});

window.alert(messages.join('\r\n'));
```

Comment: this only returns the first message. Can I concatenate the messages with a \r\n?

Comment: @gishman Yes. Just join the message array with the desired separator like `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /<message>(.*)<\/message>/gm; 
var str = '<bad xml doc>\n <a>dsda</a>\n    <message>hi</message>\n<b></b>\n  <c>dsds</c>\n<message>get this too</message>';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: This looks like it may work. Do it need single quotes around 1st line like this: var re = '/<message>(.*)<\/message>/gm';

Comment: No you don't need single quotes for the 1st line. Look at this page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hjsFo

Comment: You are welcome... if this solved your problem, then please mark the issue as solved. Regards Rdey

Comment: How do I do that? The green check?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is actually really good for parsing and traversing XML as well as HTML.  The strategy would be to create a jQuery object with your bad XML and then you can use CSS selectors to query.

For example, to alert the text inside of the 1st message:

```
var badDoc = $('<bad xml doc><a>dsda</a><message>hi</message><b></b><c>dsds</c><message>get this too</message>');
alert(badDoc.find('message')[0].innerHTML);
```